# Inserting textarea data into mySQL as text and output results

Tags: php

All,
I'm inserting some text from a textarea in a mySQL database. I'm using mysql_real_escape_string() to do this. I'm using stripslashes() to remove the "\" that gets inserted in front of this to display it. However when I output this it gives me the following result for something like wasn't I get wasn\\'t and if someone hits enter in my text area I get \r\n\r\n and that is also displayed.

In my database it stores correctly with a single slash and the return but it doesn't output that the same way when it's outputed. Any idea why it would be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are double checking how your outputting data. I used.. serialize(), and unserialize(). Takes care of any special characters it seems. Have you tried that?